# DataGridView selection changed event and deleting selected rows from database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a radiobutton, a gridview and a button on my form. Here is my `datagridview selection_changed` code sample:

```
private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rdb_Delete.Checked)
    {
        lbl_deleteMsg.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count.ToString() 
                + " rows selected.";
    }
 }
```

I want to delete selected rows from database and refresh the datagridview when user pushes the delete button. 
I have an Id column in my database but I don't show it to the user on datagridview.

So by sql query how can I delete the selected row from my database? Here is my delete button clicked code but it doesn't seems to work (because of selection changed event):

```
private void btn_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{       
    if (rdb_Delete.Checked)
    {
        int count = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count;
        int length = DataGridView1.RowCount;
        if (!count.Equals(0))
        {
            if (confirm())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    if (DataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected)
                    {
                        //DataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Selected = false;
                        DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                        i--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit : I also find a small answer maybe helps someone in such a case. DataGridView's any column can be **visible = false** so it'll be accessible by code such as :

```
int rowID = int.Parse(DataGridView1[0, selectedIndex].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539243/how-to-delete-a-selected-row-from-datagridview-and-database it might be help you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void btn_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{       
    if (rdb_Delete.Checked)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            //delete record and then remove from grid. 
            // you can use your own query but not necessary to use rowid
            int selectedIndex = row.Index;         

            // gets the RowID from the first column in the grid
            int rowID = int.Parse(DataGridView1[0, selectedIndex].Value.ToString());
            string sql = "DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE RowID = @RowID";

            // your code for deleting it from the database
            // then your code for refreshing the DataGridView

            DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try this one. It nearly does but there is no ID column on my datagridview (there is on my database but not on dgv) so it gives me a parse error. Is there any other way to delete row from database?

Comment: then you can create your query on the basis of all columns value.. pass each cell value to the query and delete that particular row.

Answer (score 0):

1.) You must use two-way binding.
2.) You must affirm the changes in order for them to be non-temporary.

Answer (score 0):

private void button60_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView7.SelectedRows)
        {
            dd = row.Cells["date"].Value.ToString();
            ms = row.Cells["month"].Value.ToString();
            day = row.Cells["day"].Value.ToString();
            string txt = row.Cells["descrip"].Value.ToString();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from holidays where date like '" + dd + "%' and descrip like '"+ txt +"'", con);
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("delete from stholidays where holiday like '" + dd + "%' and holidescrip like '" + txt + "'", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            foreach (DataGridViewCell oneCell in dataGridView7.SelectedCells)
            {

                if (oneCell.Selected)
                    dataGridView7.Rows.RemoveAt(oneCell.RowIndex);

            }
        }
```