# How to get row index according to clicked button from asp.net GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have Gridview with some records (1 record=1 row).

On every row I added a button to delete this record from my mysql db.

Every row has the same button.

The problem is I need to know **in which row the button was clicked**? I need this to get a row index to get id of my record which is in that row.

How can I do this in easiest way?

Gridview:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        CellPadding="6" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" Caption="TWOJE WIZYTY" Font-Bold="True" 
        onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated" style="text-align: left">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#AEAEAE" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="Blue" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#868686" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="Blue" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#C7C7C7" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

The button is being added like that:

```
        protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b1 = new Button();
        b1.Text = "usuń";
        b1.OnClientClick = "return potwierdzenie()";
        b1.Click+=new EventHandler(b1_Click);
        TableCell cel = new TableCell();
        cel.Width = Unit.Pixel(180);
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "";
            e.Row.Cells.Add(cel);
        }
        else
        {
            //HERE IS MY BUTTON ADDED! *********************
            cel.Controls.Add(b1);
            cel.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
            e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
            e.Row.Cells[2].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
            e.Row.Cells.Add(cel);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the markup that you are using for the GridView? Depending on how you declared the button the solution may be different.

Comment: Where is the id of the record? Are you using C# or VB.NET?

Comment: Have a look at the first answer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795325/datagridview-selection-changed-event-and-deleting-selected-rows-from-database) to get an idea - hope that helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `NamingContainer` property of your button to get the `GridViewRow`. Then you have all you need to find your other controls (f.e. the control with ID if you use `TemplateFields`).

```
protected void button_Delete_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button) sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) btn.NamingContainer;
    // assuming you store the ID in a Hiddenield:
    Hiddenield hiddenID = (HiddenField) row.FindControl("HiddenID");
    int ID = int.Parse(hiddenID.Value);
    // delete the record
}
```

You can also get the `row-index` via `row.RowIndex`.

Comment: @PawełAdamczyk: Since you have edited your question now and showed that you don't use template-fields, you cannot use `FindControl` then. But you can use `row.RowIndex` to get the index if that helps.(edited my answer acc.)