# how to delete selected rows in datagridview through delete button

Tags: c#

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection( "Data Source=AMBADNYA-PC;Initial
         Catalog=MYRAWPRO;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sa");

string query = "DELETE FROM Sales  WHERE Sales_ID =" + 
                dataGridViewProduct.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();

com.CommandText = query;
com.Connection = con;
con.Open();
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

MessageBox.Show("Deleted");
```

but it show error

```
Invalid column name 'uiui'.
```

`uiui` is the column value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using a string for Sales_ID ? this is bad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete a selected row from datagridview and database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539243/how-to-delete-a-selected-row-from-datagridview-and-database)